# I dont understand how following C language code gives output as 22

Tags: c, output, logic

```
#include<stdio.h>

int rec(int num)
{
    return(num) ? num % 10 + rec(num / 10) : 0;

}
int main()
{
    printf("\n%d\n", rec(4567));
}
```

IDE used is visual studio 2017 64 bit.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code. Use pen and paper to write down intermediate values.

Comment: Do you understand what [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) is?

Comment: I do . But with ternary operator i am not able to visualise the working of code.

Comment: OK - rewrite it to avoid the ternary operator, (not a bad plan in any case, IMHO:).  Throw in a few temp vars for extra clarity and ease of debugging.  If you are in a position to, fire the original author:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is calculating each number mod 10 (first run is 4567 % 10 = 7). It then runs recursively (`rec(num/10)`), calling the function on 456, then on 45, then on 4.

Since it is adding the number it comes up with to the recursive function (`num % 10 + rec(num / 10)`), your function is  just adding (4567 % 10 + 456 % 10 + 45 % 10 + 4 % 10) which is just 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 = 22.

Comment: Thank you , finally understood the logic , this was bugging me for last two hours, now I can sleep peacefully thank you again.